# Automatically populating date in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the date to populate in a column AC (29) of the google sheet, when I enter deployed in Column Y (25). Here is the script I've currently created, and can't figure out why it's not working.

function onEdit(e) {

```
var colToWatch = 25, colToStamp = 29;
var valueToWatch = "Deployed"; 
if (e.range.columnStart === colToWatch && (e.value === valueToWatch || typeof e.value == 'object'))
e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
    .setValue(typeof e.value === 'object' ? null : new Date());
```

}

Comment: Why isn't it working? Any specific error messages? Unexpected behavior? Can you post a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

`columnStart()` and `rowStart()` are not methods available to the Range object in Google Apps Script. You need to use `getColumn()` and `getRow()` instead. Checking the value type multiple times seems unnecessary given that you're already using `===`, and it's not listed in your problem description, so I'm removing it. Moreover, the `typeof` value is necessarily going to be a string–it will never be an object.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var colToWatch = 25, colToStamp = 29;
  var valueToWatch = "Deployed"; 
  if (e.range.getColumn() === colToWatch && e.value === valueToWatch) {
    e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), colToStamp).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Diego, thank you for the help. I copied the script just as listed above and it's still not populating the dates. Any other ideas?

Comment: To add some additional background. Column 25 is being populated from another sheet using importrange. So "Deployed" actually gets populated in sheet 1, and then imported into sheet 2. I'm pretty sure this is the issue, because if I type Deployed directly into Column 25 in this sheet, it works. Is there a way to do it knowing this data is imported? If not, I'll just do the calculation in the original sheet and then copy that over as well.

Comment: @ToddL That is definitely the reason why it won't trigger. You'll either need to do as you've indicated and make the calculation in the original sheet or you could create a time-trigger that runs every x minutes to check for updated values.

Comment: @Diego Would it be something as simple as adding this to the script above.              function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 5 minutes.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(5)
      .create(); }

Comment: No, you would need to modify the script to check all values in columns 25 and 29. Then you could add the trigger, but I recommend that you use the GUI menu option for creating as it's easier.